# Auto complete in webmatrix 3

Tags: javascript, html, css, autocomplete, webmatrix

Webmatrix 3 has the intelisense feature that enables it to autocomplete tags and stuffs . 
But once in a  tutorial i saw that it was able to even auto complete some style options which were from seperate files

ex :

i have an index.html 
and i have bootstrap at  css/bootstrap.css

inside it

```
<html> 



.
.
// when i type 
// <button type="button" class="btn 

//i want it  to have 

 <button type="button" class="btn btn-default // and much more options 
</html>
```

how do u enable this feature ? 
or doesn anyone know any other editor which can  do this ? 
thanks in advance

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Actually i found another IDE   **jetbrains** Which had this functionality that i was expecting ...
its good bye webmatrix :)

Answer (score 0):

Nope, WebMatrix only allows you to use the code inside your **App_Code** folder such as the Class Files or NameSpaces you create yourself. For example if you create this file

```
using NameSpace; /* any of the */

public class someClass {
  public int someMethod (int[] params) {
    /* code for the method */
  }
}
```

Now when you'll write `new someClass()` you'll be prompted to use the method i.e. `someMethod()` and the parameters would be told to you.

But remember, this won't work for any other folder that you're using. Such as Scripts, Content etc. The Script part has the JavaScript files that you include, so it won't allow you to use features that a third party such as jQuery would let you handle. You're more likely to write them all yourself. But the folders that are created or are generally for ASP.NET Web Pages, for example: **App_Code**, **App_Data**, you can access them all by using the IntelliSense.

New versions of WebMatrix might also let you to use this feature for all the folders. But that would be hard enough for the developers as they would have to look for the entire project for some JS file or CSS file and then get all the methods and properties.

Your file (Twitter Bootstrap) ain't gonna get integrated into WebMatrix just as jQuery or any other third party file. WebMatrix shows you for the pure programming language such as CSS, JavaScript, ASP.NET or any of the code you include in the **bin** or **App_Code** or **App_Data** folder, I am not sure about App_Data as that includes the Databases and you're not gonna use that folder without Connecting to the Database.

You're still at luck: http://webmatrix.uservoice.com/forums/128313-webmatrix-suggestions Suggest this at the link I have provided you with. And you might get this option in the next version of the WebMatrix.